# Conversion from int16 to unsigned int16 may overflow

Tags: type-conversion, unsigned, signed, misra

After Polyspace code check I am getting "conversion from int16 to unsigned int16 may overflow".

```
uint16 lData = 0x00u;
sint16 AnalogInputValue;
lData = (uint16)AnalogInputValue; => This line causes Polyspace error
```

Should the type cast do the job ? According to Polyspace no :)

Comment: Why do you have a variable "analoginputvalue" which is signed, in the first place? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: These are only selected lines. signed variable is filled with the signed value after function call etc .... In order to keep it simple are only these lines copied ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to assure that AnalogInputValue does not contain any negative numbers before you type cast it as uint16. If you do ot do that then you risk to loose data in the type cast.

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines do the same thing:

```
lData = AnalogInputValue;
lData = (uint16)AnalogInputValue;
```

Why?  The target of the assignment `lData` is of type `uint16`, therefore the value stored in the variable `AnalogInputValue` will have to be converted to `uint16` in either case.  The variable `AnalogInputValue`, however, is of type `sint16`.

The warning comes from the following fact: Variables of type `uint16` can hold values in the range 0..65535.  But, variables of type `sint16` can typically hold values in the range -32768..32767.  Therefore, if `AnalogInputValue` happens to hold a value in the range -32768..-1, then this value can not be represented by an `uint16`.

Therefore, before doing the assignment, you might add some code around it that checks that `AnalogInputValue` is not negative.  Which means, it holds a value from 0..32767.  All these values can be represented in `uint16`.  And, for the other case, namely that the check reveals that `AnalogInputValue` happens to be negative, you have to find some acceptable solution.

There is one potential third scenario here: You are 100% sure that `AnalogInputValue` will never hold a negative value, but the logic is too complex for Polyspace to deduce that fact, or the data comes from an external source (which seems to be the case here, as the value is called `AnalogInputValue`).  Then, adding an assertion before the assignment can be used as a means to instruct Polyspace that it shall make this assumption.